# What's the importance of sshd's setting RekeyLimit?

Tags: ssh

`man sshd_config` page states:

> ### RekeyLimit
>
> Specifies the maximum amount of data that may be transmitted  before the session key is renegotiated, optionally followed a  maximum amount of time that may pass before the session key is  renegotiated. [...] The default value for **RekeyLimit** is "default none", which means that rekeying is performed after the cipher's default amount of data has been sent or received and no time based rekeying is done.  This option applies to protocol version 2 only.

Let's suppose I have a very long-running (days/weeks) connection, with gigabytes transferred to and fro. Will it make any difference in the level of protection against mid-level threats if I set the value to anything other than the default of no time-based rekeying?

Will this setting prevent any unusual attacks or, inversely, present an attacker with unique opportunities? Does it matter what ciphers and cipher modes are employed (CBC vs CTR vs OpenSSH's GCM implementation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea behind rekeying is that session keys may be susceptible to some unspecified attack, such as direct cryptanalysis or side-channel attack. A common theme in most attacks is that they require the analysis of a large amount of encrypted data to execute. By limiting the amount of data transmitted with a single session key, you can effectively thwart a large portion of attacks against your encryption keys, whatever those attacks may be.

The cipher and chaining method you use does affect the type and effectiveness of attack an adversary might deploy. But the defense of rotating your session key after a few GB is a reasonably effective mitigation strategy.

Comment: I'd like to add some precision to the answer. Both GCM and CTR modes of AES require IV aka nonce to be used only once for a given key. If this condition is not met, the security of the whole construct fails catastrophically.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, when you chose appropriate values (traffic amount and time limit), you should mainly consider the running time of the connection and the traffic. If you don't have sufficient amount of traffic, then the time limit should assure that the session key is renegotiated in a timely manner to "prevent" any time dependent attacks (such as a sophisticated attack against the key space). On the other hand, if you have a lot of traffic, you don't want to set the traffic limit to too low, so it doesn't have to renegotiate the key too often.

This option is mainly concern to prevent any attacks which are traffic amount or time dependant, hence I doubt it will directly present any new opportunities for attack.

The employed cipher matters to some extend, hence the default traffic amount is set between [1G and 4G](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=ssh_config) depending on the cipher.

Based on the information provided by you, I think you should be mainly concern to set a limit on the traffic amount which is not too low. Time limit could be an useful addition while not necessary if believe that the traffic amount on the connection won't be significantly reduced for a long period of time.

Comment: Broken link (404)